# Why does changing position from relative to absolute change the background image size?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and css.  If I change the position attribute from absolute to relative, the div.raw seems to flow within the html layout and the background image doesn't cover up everything.  If I do not, then it does.  Why is this?

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="push">Hello World</h1>
<div class="container">
  Some text
<div class="raw"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.push {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.raw {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: auto;
  background-image: url("http://st-im.kinopoisk.ru/im/wallpaper/2/3/0/kinopoisk.ru-True-Detective-2300505--w--1280.jpg");
  //background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioned elements position fixed to their ancestor which need to have a positioning. in your case the ancestor 'container' has no position so div.raw positions itself like fixed to the viewport. in fact if you set raw's position to fixed you see that it is the same as absolute. however once you set a position to container (relative for instance) that absolute and fixed makes difference.

same result here with absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/0ugp2p2w/2/

once you put this

```
.container {
      position:relative;
}
```

notice the result is different

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/0ugp2p2w/

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/0ugp2p2w/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/0ugp2p2w/3/

Answer (score 0):

Because the absolute positioned element's relative dimensions are related to whole document, relative positioned element's relative dimensions are related to its parent element.